# Снижается ли скорость загрузки сайта, если изображения будут открываться при помощи клика?

Tags: javascript, html, css, оптимизация-сайтов

Снижается ли скорость загрузки сайта, если изображения будут открываться при помощи клика? Если допостим на одной странице сайта 100+ изображений весом 1мб, НО открываться будут при помощи клика.

Comment: Если браузер не будет пред-загружать картинки, то скорость загрузки и отрисовки html может увеличится. При этом при нажатии на "пустую" картинку (она ведь не загружалась) пользователь будет ждать 1-5 секунду для загрузки и отрисовки этой картинки.

Comment: Может лучше использовать атрибут `loading="lazy"`?

Answer (score 0):

Да. Но вам нужно реализовать именно загрузку изображения по клику. То есть браузер не должен видеть URL изображения заранее и соответственно не должен его загружать раньше.

Вот примерно как то так https://habr.com/ru/post/189764/

Но я думаю может быть странный экспирианс у пользователя от ожидания загрузки картинки после клика) Возможно реализовать что то типа кэширования еще до клика на картинку как с статье выше.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Ссылаться на внешний материал конечно хорошо, но также нужно оставлять цитаты (и код если имеется) из ссылок, чтобы пользователи понимали что из ждёт из ссылки, а также это будет полезно если доступ к ресурсу был потерян. Подробнее [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).